Easy way to distinguish between malformed S3 directory URI and valid S3 file URI?
Suppose I am given a path
s3://my-bucket/foo/bar

What is the smart way, without downloading the file, to determine whether or not the s3 URI refers to a file or is simply a malformed directory?
I would prefer a solution that uses boto3.
